# NavHostFragment.findNavController can't be applied to a fragment error

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am creating a time prompter app for a sport activity. Not able to move back from Settings Fragment  to Launcher Fragment. The code is similar to code that moves back from Action Fragment to Launcher Fragment successfully. I am getting error here that findNavController in NavHostFragment cannot be applied to SettingsFragment. It also says SettingsFragment cannot be converted to Fragment.

```
            public void onClick(View view) {
                NavHostFragment.findNavController(SettingsFragment.this)
                        .navigate(R.id.action_SettingsFragment_to_LauncherFragment);
```

```
public class SettingsFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentSettingsBinding binding;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState
    ) {
        binding = FragmentSettingsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);

        return binding.getRoot();
    }
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        binding.goBackButtonSettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                NavHostFragment.findNavController(SettingsFragment.this)
                        .navigate(R.id.action_SettingsFragment_to_LauncherFragment);
            }
        });
    }



}
```

SettingsFragment xml is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:contentDescription="@string/start_action"
    android:foregroundTint="@color/teal_700"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    tools:context=".SettingsFragment">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/goBackButtonSettings"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:background="@color/teal_200"
        android:backgroundTint="#F57F17"
        android:text="@string/goback"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.96"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Not able to locate where exactly the code is wrong and fix it. Need help.

Comment: It sounds like you're importing the wrong `Fragment` class - are you sure you are importing `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`?

Comment: @ianhanniballake, Thanks for the suggestion. It worked as I was using earlier different import. Substituting with `androidx.fragment.app.fragment` worked.